# Correlation matrix giving the wrong value in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I wanted to get the correlation matrix for an actual value and a predicted value, but the results after the first column are wrong.
There are many missing values in my dataframe.

This is the code:

```
# Create different tables for overall (actual) and potential (predicted) values for every year
actual <- table %>%
                select(starts_with('overall_'))

predicted <- table %>%
                select(starts_with('potential_'))

# Create a matrix for r of every year
cormat <- round( cor(
               x = actual, y = predicted,
               use = "complete.obs",
               method = "pearson"),
              3)
cormat
```

[image: Result matrix]

However when I calculate the correlation manually the resut is different.

```
round( 
      cor(table$overall_15,
          table$potential_15,
          use = "complete.obs"), 3)
# Result: 0.804
```

Anybody knows why?

Thank you,

Comment: The „larger“ code will delete missings from all of your actual/potential columns wheres the code for _15 only deletes missings in these two columns. That might explain the difference.

Comment: You could change the use to 'pairwise.complete.obs'.